# how to use Twilio SMS params[:Body] to search a rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms, twilio

Hello I'm trying to search my database to find a recipe from the body of an SMS using twilio.  Here is my code so far in the controller

```
 def process_sms
    @recipe = Recipe.find_by(params[:title])
    render 'process_sms.xml.erb', :content_type => 'text/xml'
  end
```

and my routes:

```
root          'recipes#index'
  devise_for    :users
  resources     :recipes
  post          'twilio/voice' => 'twilio#voice'
  post          'twiliosms/send_sms' => 'twiliosms#send_sms'
  match         'twiliosms/process_sms' => 'twiliosms#process_sms', via: :all
```

I'd like to be able to search for the Recipe title from the SMS and render some xml.  The current implementation keeps sending back the same recipe over and over again.  I think it has something to do with not passing the twilio `params[:Body]` in the same controller action and using that to match a `recipe(params[:title])` but not completely sure.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You've mentioned `params[:Body]`, which is the parameter in which the text from the SMS message will be, however you are using `params[:title]` to search with. In the context of an incoming webhook from Twilio, `params[:title]` will be nil, so I would guess your recipe that is being returned has no title.

I think you should be using:

```
def process_sms
  @recipe = Recipe.find_by(title: params[:Body])
  render 'process_sms.xml.erb', :content_type => 'text/xml'
end
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

**[edit]**
Updated call to `find_by`

Comment: Hi @philnash I get the following internal server error.  Let me know what you think.  thanks!'Recipe Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE (Tacos) LIMIT 1
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: Tacos: SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE (Tacos) LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: Tacos: SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE (Tacos) LIMIT 1):
  app/controllers/twiliosms_controller.rb:26:in `process_sms''

Comment: 'SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: Tacos: SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE (Tacos) LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)'  It's basically telling me that there is not Body column in my schema, I believe.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, the `find_by` method doesn't just take a string. Updated it in my answer to `Recipe.find_by(title: params[:Body])`. Try that.

Comment: That's assuming that your model has a `title` field, which I'm guessing from your context.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Would love to know what you're building, feel free to drop me an email on philnash@twilio.com!

Answer (score 1):

you might consider using a `.where` in your controller function (assuming your model column is named "title"):

```
def process_sms
  @recipe = Recipe.where(title:params[:title])
  render 'process_sms.xml.erb', :content_type => 'text/xml'
end
```

Comment: Hey The Fabio, thanks for your response I tried that and it rendered the #<recipe::ActiveRecord_relation: > when I tried @recipe.title .  And Ideas on how to render the actual data?

Comment: do you mind adding rails logs around calling the "process_sms" action to your question? This might show another clue.